# Conversion from N,E to Lat/Long And Lat/Long to N,E will always be same?

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system, proj, utm

I have an excel tool for the conversion of following lat/long:

Lat: 23° 11’ 24.67503’’ S
Long: 118° 46’ 6.15742’’ E , which gives me following N,E:

Northing: 7,434,317.43

Easting: 680,991.69

But I am not clear that why conversion of the N,E back to Lat/Long is not giving me same results i.e. Lat: 23° 11’ 24.67503’’ S

Long: 118° 46’ 6.15742’’ E

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Which UTM Zone are you working with?

Comment: Exactly what results do you get in the conversion back to lat/lon?  In the example you give it appears the reconversion is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

first of all pls check out your accept rate for users..

---

in excel cell formating can gives you wrong result... use to develop your own code for conversion.

for converting dms to ll:

```
function DMStoLL(degrees, minutes, seconds){
   return degrees + minutes / 60 + seconds / 3600
}
```

for converting ll to dms:

```
function LLtoDMS(coord){
   var d = parseInt(coord);
   var md = Math.abs(coord - d) * 60;
   var m = parseInt(md);
   var sd = (md-m) * 60;
   return [d, m, sd.toFixed(9)];
    }
```

and you can get more information [here](http://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/usefuldata/utmformulas.htm) Converting UTM to Latitude and Longitude (Or Vice Versa)

for utm, you can calculate your clicked zone as sth....

```
var clicked = map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(evt.xy).transform(map.projection, 
              map.displayProjection);

var zone = (clicked + 186) / 6;
```

you have to calculate your n,e with your utm zone. if you tell us i can give some formule too..

i hope it helps you...

Comment: UTM zone should be 50S (Western Australia). You have to consider that you are in the southern hemisphere, so North lat should probably be negative, and UTM North zero is at the south pole.